# Как сделать ImageView динамически(из кода) с заданными параметрами

Tags: java, android

Имеется ImageView, нужно сделать точно такое же View из кода.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image15"
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="91dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image14"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter">
</ImageView>
```

Как я понимаю нужно сделать как то так

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
image.setLayoutParams...
```

а как дальше установить все нужные атрибуты я не знаю. Плюс ко всему, я не понимаю как мне обращаться к нужному id View компонента из класса ресурсов

P.S. А потом под этим компонентом сгенерировать еще одно точно такое же View.

Comment: Можно сделать шаблон xml и из него создавать https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/80-urok-40-layoutinflater-uchimsja-ispolzovat.html , обращаться можно по индексу в группе getChildAt

Answer (score 1):

Какой контейнер вы используете? Судя по below - RelativeLayout, но в нем не поддерживается свойство weigth. Если его откидываем, то будет так

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
image.setId(R.id.image15) //для того, чтобы это сработало, среди ваших xml разметок должен где-то упоминаться этот id, иначе в классе R его не будет. А вообще вы можете сами придумать любое число и задать его этой командой как id.
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)//создаем LayoutParams для размещения элемента в RelativeLayout. Если элемент будет размещаться в LinearLayout, то брать реализацию LayoutParams надо будет оттуда и т.д.
image.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.image14) //добавляем привязку "под объект"
image.setLayoutParams(lp)
```

А вообще можно вбить в гугл запрос вида "android ImageView %имя атрибута% programmatically" и по первой же ссылке в 95% случаев будет страница с нужным примером